# Genus of arithmetic surface groups

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, fuchsian-groups, arithmetic-groups

It is known that for each genus, only finitely many points in the moduli space of hyperbolic genus g surfaces are arithmetic.  I'm wondering if an existence result is known: for which g do we have examples of arithmetic Fuchsian genus g surface groups?  What about surfaces with boundary?

Comment: If you're interested in congruence arithmetic groups, consider:
http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2251482
http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1654474

Answer (score 8):

If there is an arithmetic group of genus $2$ (which there is, see http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa86/aa8626.pdf), then there are such of all genera, by taking finite index subgroups. The argument for non-uniform (cusped) groups is the same. The question for maximal such groups is more interesting, and I am not sure what the answer is...

Comment: One could also ask for *congruence* groups, which is more general than maximal arithmetic groups but still much more restrictive than arbitrary arithmetic groups, perhaps sufficiently so to be "interesting".